# Excel, checking for one value in one column and another value in another

Tags: excel

I thought this would be easy to find online, but I was wrong. This is what I'm trying to do.

For example, I have this data table:

```
A    B
100  3
100  5
100  6
200  2
200  3
200  5
300  1
300  2
300  6
```

Now I want to check if a certain "set of values" exist or not.
For example input of (100,3) would exist. Input of (300,4) would not exist, but (300,6) would exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your search criteria are in `E2` (for column A) and `F2` (for column B), use

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,F2)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

For a specific combination - like your example (100,3) -- you could use the formula `=countifs(a:a,100,b:b,3)>0`.

If you wish to know all the combinations that exist then I'd suggest inserting a pivot table.